# Getting Different timestamp when Converting same Unix time in Two Different DB

Tags: mysql, oracle, timezone, utc

MySql Query :

```
select FROM_UNIXTIME(1387444958) from dual;
```

Output :

```
2013-12-19 10:22:38
```

Oracle Query :

```
select to_char(to_date('01/01/1970 00:00:00',
  'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')+ (1387444958/86400),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')from dual;
```

output:

```
2013-12-19 09:22:38
```

Can anyone explain me the reason why i am getting difference and also help me in getting same result.

Comment: Maybe it has to do with the time zone of your  MySQL  session settings. It gives 9:22 in dbfiddle see [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f4b8dbf9e972a6291f2082c158bc1e41) . Also in [Oracle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ff010fba8f32fe462f1f86b7347e646d) :

Comment: @KaushikNayak could you help me in getting resolve ? or if you can just share the steps that i need to perform in mySQL

Comment: I'm not too familiar with MySQL datetime / session specific statements. Please wait for experts to arrive to answer your question.

Comment: ok @KaushikNayak Thank you for quick response.